# Swift NSData contentsOfURL

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I started to learn swift on treehouse and Im trying to create a weather app.
I fixed some errors that were caused by deprecated  NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL

My final code

```
let apiKey = "apiString"


let baseURL: NSURL? = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apiKey)/")
let forecastURL: NSURL? = NSURL(string: "37.8267,-122.423", relativeToURL: baseURL)

if let weatherData = NSData(contentsOfURL: forecastURL!, options: nil, error: nil) {
    println("Ok it works \(forecastURL!)")
}
else{
    println("Some error")

}
```

But constant weatherData is nil and my console output shows

> 2014-12-03 11:30:52.868 MyPlayground[6542:887800]
>   NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807) Some error

I tried with some other websites and it seems like theres is a problem with https://

Comment: Are you getting data when you are hitting with same url on browser?

Comment: Yes and also as I wrote it just didnt work with https I also tried https://treehouse....... to get data from some post on their website